# How to test if the connection to H2O in r was successful in R

Tags: r, h2o

I am running the following code to connect to H2O in R and getting the output below:
    h2o.init(nthreads=-1, max_mem_size = paste(x,"g", sep = ""))

```
R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
H2O cluster uptime:         3 minutes 57 seconds 
H2O cluster version:        3.14.0.3 
H2O cluster version age:    3 days  
H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_rami_krispin 
H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
H2O cluster total memory:   0.88 GB 
H2O cluster total cores:    4 
H2O cluster allowed cores:  4 
H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
H2O Connection port:        54321 
H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
H2O API Extensions:         Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4 
R Version:                  R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
```

Is there a way to capture into boolean variable whatever the connection was successful (something like `is.h2o.connect()` with response of True/False) and the attribute of the connection into variable? For example:

```
x$port
>54321
```

or

```
x$memory
>0.88 GB
```

Thank you in advance!
Rami

Comment: is `h2o.clusterIsUp()` what you want for the first question?

Comment: That was fast! any yes! thanks!

Comment: and then `h2o.clusterInfo()` gives you the info that is printed to the console. To get it into an R objet you'll need a way of capturing & parsing it I think

Answer (score 3):

To see if the cluster is up you can use

```
h2o.clusterIsUp()
# TRUE
```

and to see the connection info you can use

```
h2o.getConnection()

IP Address: localhost 
Port      : 54321 
Session ID: _sid_b51e 
Key Count : 0
```

Then you can use some of the internal `h2o` functions to get all the meta about the connection

```
res <- h2o:::.h2o.fromJSON(
         jsonlite::fromJSON(
           h2o:::.h2o.doSafeGET(
             urlSuffix = h2o:::.h2o.__CLOUD
           ), 
           implifyDataFrame = FALSE
         )
       )

str(res)
List of 19
 $ __meta                   :List of 3
  ..$ schema_version: int 3
  ..$ schema_name   : chr "CloudV3"
  ..$ schema_type   : chr "Iced"
 $ _exclude_fields          : chr ""
 $ skip_ticks               : logi TRUE
 $ version                  : chr "3.10.4.6"
 $ branch_name              : chr "rel-ueno"
 $ build_number             : chr "6"
 $ build_age                : chr "4 months and 30 days"
 $ build_too_old            : logi TRUE
 $ node_idx                 : int 0
 $ cloud_name               : chr "H2O_started_from_R_david_tos519"
 $ cloud_size               : int 1
 $ cloud_uptime_millis      : int 772951
 $ cloud_healthy            : logi TRUE
 $ bad_nodes                : int 0
 $ consensus                : logi TRUE
 $ locked                   : logi TRUE
 $ is_client                : logi FALSE
 $ nodes                    :List of 1
  ..$ :List of 27
  .. ..$ __meta        :List of 3
  .. .. ..$ schema_version: int 3
  .. .. ..$ schema_name   : chr "NodeV3"
  .. .. ..$ schema_type   : chr "Iced"
... etc
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, `h2o.clusterStatus()` is providing the connection attributes

```
                           h2o healthy    last_ping
1 localhost/127.0.0.1:54321    TRUE 1.506398e+12
  num_cpus  sys_load mem_value_size  free_mem
1        4 0.2445616           5120 783876096
   pojo_mem swap_mem    free_disk     max_disk
1 170846208        0 310012542976 510426873856
   pid num_keys tcps_active open_fds rpcs_active
1 7084       20           0       -1           0
```